# json.net DataTable Deserialixe returns null

Tags: c#, json, datatable, json.net

I used json.net to serialize and deserialize my datatable. This is successfully serialized but when deserialized it returns empty

My service method is follows

```
    public string GetData()
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable("MyData");
        dt.Columns.Add("Name");
        dt.Columns.Add("Age");

        DataRow dr1 = dt.NewRow();
        dr1[0] = "Name1";
        dr1[1] = 20;
        dt.Rows.Add(dr1);

        DataRow dr2 = dt.NewRow();
        dr2[0] = "Name2";
        dr2[1] = 23;
        dt.Rows.Add(dr2);

        DataRow dr3 = dt.NewRow();
        dr3[0] = "Name3";
        dr3[1] = 28;
        dt.Rows.Add(dr3);


        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dt, new DataTableConverter());
  }
```

My web page code is follows

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // corrected to WebRequest from HttpWebRequest
        WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("http://ltms10/lamiservice/Service1.svc/GetData");

        request.Method = "GET";
        request.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";

        //get response-stream, and use a streamReader to read the content
        using (WebResponse response = request.GetResponse())
        {
            using (Stream s = response.GetResponseStream())
            {
                using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(s))
                {
                    var jsonData = sr.ReadToEnd();
                    Label1.Text = jsonData;

                    DataTable dt = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataTable>(jsonData);
                    grd1.DataSource = dt;
                    grd1.DataBind();

                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Here string is return like below

"[{\"Name\":\"Name1\",\"Age\":\"20\"},{\"Name\":\"Name2\",\"Age\":\"23\"},{\"Name\":\"Name3\",\"Age\":\"28\"}]"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem that the format is the problem. When i read using JSONTextReader it is converted successfully. So the escaped characters are skipped. I also check in Console.WriteLine() also got the correct data

Original data is

[{"Name":"Name1","Age":20},{"Name":"Name2","Age":23},{"Name":"Name3","Age":28}]

But how to format this in JQuery. Because of this escape character jquery chart is not binding

Update:

I got the soultion that we need to chnage the data to real json format by avoidng escape characters. For this we can use JSONTextReader class. I don't know this is the correct way to do. But this is a work around for this issue and got the deserialized datatable. The changed code is below

using (WebResponse response = request.GetResponse())
                {

```
                using (Stream s = response.GetResponseStream())
                {
                    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(s))
                    {
                        var jsonData = sr.ReadToEnd();
                        JsonTextReader reader = new JsonTextReader(new StringReader(jsonData));
                        string data="";
                        while (reader.Read())
                        {
                            if (reader.Value != null)
                                data += reader.Value;
                        }

                        DataTable dt = (DataTable)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(data, typeof(DataTable));

                        grd1.DataSource = dt;
                        grd1.DataBind();

                    }
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
DataTable dt = (DataTable) JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonData, (typeof(DataTable)));
```

Comment: Tried. But same result. empty.